# I am covered with random pixels

Tags: riddle

What 2-word noun satisfies this?

> I am not created in China, but on Japan.
>
> But I am covered with random pixels,
>
> Some people use me in Discord,
>
> And people share me to go to a specific thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably

> QR code (or Quick Response if the abbreviation is not counted as a word)

That's because

> QR codes are originated in Japan, consist of apparently random pixels, and the primary purpose of them is sharing links.